# Find an abelian infinite group such that every proper subgroup is finite

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

I found this question in Arhangel'skii and Tkachenko's book *Topological Groups and Related Structures*. The first chapter of the book is devoted to algebraic preliminaries.

The question actually reads:

> Give an example of an infinite abelian group all proper subgroups of which are finite.

What I have done is:
Every element of this group has finite order, else we could find an infinite proper subgroup, namely the group generated by $x²$ if $x$ has infinite order.

I think this can be strengthened: every element should have a prime order. Although I haven't proved this.

Intuitively this group cannot be and infinite product of smaller groups, because you could take the product of the even group factors and find an infinite proper subgroup.

Well, this is it, a highly non-trivial problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could look up the construction of a Tarski monster.

Comment: wow that answers it!
Do you know where I can find such a construction?

Comment: "Every element of this group has finite order, else we could find an infinite proper subgroup, namely the group generated by $x^2$ if $x$ has infinite order." How can you be certain that $<x^2>$ is a proper subgroup? Could it be the original group itself?

Comment: Tarski Monsters are not abelian groups, so they are not relevant to this problem.

Comment: They may not be abelian, but they have the most desired property. So it's a very good partial answer.

Comment: @Code-Guru if $x$ has infinite order, then it's impossible for $x$ to be a member of the group $\langle x^2\rangle$ - can you see why?

Comment: @BrettFrankel The construction of Tarski Monster groups is not easy - it uses a rather complicated "graded" small cancellation theory (but this is a useful tool for your toolbox, and is not too complicated in itself). It can be found in the book *The Geometry of Defining Relations in Groups* by A. Yu Ol'shanskii (1991 - translated from the Russian in 1994 I think). The book is easier than the original papers, for some value of "easier"...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

More generally, you can show that the abelian groups whose proper subgroups are finite are precisely the [Prüfer groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) $\mathbb{Z}[p^{\infty}]$.

(Mentioned in Kaplansky's book, *Infinite abelian groups*, exercice 23.)

Comment: now is this a full answer?

Answer (score 38):

Consider the set of all $2^n$-th roots of unity, as $n$ ranges over the non-negative integers.  An infinite subgroup involves elements of arbitrarily high order, which generate everything below them.

Comment: Just checked. This is a perfect answer.

So the problem was trivial after all.

Comment: In retrospect, at least not hard, if one thinks about the kind of tower we need.

Comment: Did not go that deep in group theory.
just starting the incantations on that realm.

Comment: Now, does anyone know where I can find the construction of them Tarski monsters?

Comment: It is not clear to me how the last sentence holds.

Comment: @leo: There are $m$ $m$-th roots of unity, so for any infinite subgroup $A$, there must be a sequence $2{n_1}\lt 2^{n_2}\lt \cdots$ such that $A$ contains a primitive $2^{n_i}$-th root of unity. But if $k\lt n_i$, and $g$ is a primitive $2^{n_i}$-th root of unity, and $a$ is a $2^k$-th root of unity, then $a$ is a power of $g$.

Comment: Now I see. Under that hypothesis, it was just equate two things which are both 1. Thanks

Comment: "Sometimes it is non-trivial to see that something is trivial." :)