# Infinite group must have infinite subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that an Infinite group must have subgroup with infinite elements.

I know that if group was cyclic order of the generator is infinite and there are infinite number of divisors.

Comment: Do you mean that it must have an infinite number of subgroups or subgroups which are infinite?

Comment: @DonAntonio infinite number of subgroups. Edited the question.

Comment: @Surya I think you should ask this as a separate question, so as not to nullify Trevor Wilson's answer.

Comment: (But for a hint: Consider the subgroup generated by each element. When do these subgroups precisely coincide?)

Comment: @user1729 ok edited it back.

Comment: For the other interpretation of the question, you can check the thread [Finite number of subgroups ⇒ finite group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22996/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any group is a subgroup of itself.

Comment: If we disallow this trivial case, the statement is wrong: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261145/find-an-abelian-infinite-group-such-that-every-proper-subgroup-is-finite

Comment: Is the statement still true if disallow trivial groups?

Comment: @Surya Do you mean trivial cases? That is what Trevor Wilson saying. The trivial group is finite...

Answer (score 1):

There are infinite groups with no infinite proper subgroups.
Even if the group is abelian, as show the $p$-component of $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ (that is the set of elements whose order is a power of $p$), for any prime number $p$.

Tarski monsters provide examples in the non abelian case.

Comment: However, all known examples are infinitely presented. Which is interesting.

Comment: May be you can edit the question to include your remark.  Or better ask the question independently : Is there a finitely presented infinite group in which every proper subgroup is finite?

Comment: When I said "all known examples" I meant *all known examples* (not just those known by me). It is a relatively famous open problem, related to Burnside's problem. See the discussion following Problem 1.1 of [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2899) list of problems.

Comment: I remember well, that I found the Riemann Hypothesis as an exercise in Serge Lang's "Complex Analysis".