# Non-trivial finite/infinite subgroups of infinite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Does an infinite group whose every non-trivial subgroup is also infinite exist? If yes, what can be an example of such a group?

also,

Does an infinite group whose every non-trivial subgroup is finite exist? If yes, what can be an example of such a group?

Comment: The free group on 2 elements? It is the group made of words over the alphabet $a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1}$, with concatenation as multiplication.

Comment: @Ranveer, in the second part of the question, I think you want the first occurrence of "finite" to be "infinite", no?

Comment: Now this is the final question. I'm really sorry for the typos and thanks @Doc for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: just edit out the "also" in "also finite" and you're good.

Comment: For abelian examples, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261145

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any group without non-trivial elements of finite order has this property (and the converse also holds). One example is $\mathbb{Z}$.

For your second question, one example is the group $\{x \in \mathbb{C} : \exists n \in \mathbb{N}\: \: x^{2^n} = 1\}$ under multiplication.

Comment: A very nice example that is also easy to understand.  Well done!

Comment: Why are all the subgroups finite?

Answer (score 5):

There exist infinite groups all of whose proper subgroups are finite.  Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group

The Tarski Monster is another example .. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group

Comment: The point of the Tarski monster group is that it is finitely generated, while the Prufer groups are not (just so you know the motivation...).