# Simple examples of infinite groups containing non-trivial finite subgroups?

Tags: group-theory

What are some non-trivial examples of finite subgroups of infinite groups? An example is simpler to understand than another if the background required to understand the example is less than the other.

I discount the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572853/non-trivial-finite-infinite-subgroups-of-infinite-groups) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261145/find-an-abelian-infinite-group-such-that-every-proper-subgroup-is-finite) because they answer the question: "which infinite groups have **all** infinite subgroups, or **all** finite subgroups?". (also the answers aren't particularly simple)

This question is dropping the **all**, and is dropping the request for infinite subgroups. However, this question is not dropping the triviality condition, as the simplest example I can think of is the trivial example: the sub-group containing only the identity element.

Comment: What are you non-trivial examples ? There might be too many examples. Just take a finite group $\Gamma_1$ and any other group $\Gamma_2$, then the free product $\Gamma_1*\Gamma_2$ contains $\Gamma_1$ as a subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix group $M_2(\Bbb{R})$ is infinite, and has a finite cyclic subgroup $C_2$ of diagonal matrices $id,-id$.

Answer (score 1):

The infinite group $SO(3)$ of all 3d rotations has many finite subgroups, including for example the symmetry groups of solids (e.g., a dodecahedron $\implies A_5$, or a regular prism $\implies D_{2n}$) in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Doe the infinite group of all 2D rotations not have such finite subgroups?