# If every proper subgroup of a group is finite, does it follow that the group is finite?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that every proper subgroup of a group is finite.

Does it imply that the group is finite?

Comment: No, consider $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120829/an-infinite-group-such-that-every-proper-subgroup-is-finite

Comment: For what it's worth, the example by @Jean-ClaudeArbaut is called the Prufer $p$-group.

Comment: @Nishant: that group has lots of proper infinite subgroups, e.g. the Prufer $p$-groups for a fixed prime $p$.

Comment: @Behaviour It might not be. Notice how that question asks for an abelian group and this is just a group.

Comment: @Alizter An abelian example automatically gives an example for this group.

Comment: For a nonabelian example, just take direct limit of all finite groups, as said in the comments on the MO post.

Comment: @BalarkaSen Yes but example for non-abelian which is enough reason not to close this question.

Comment: @Alizter Fair enough, withdrew my vote and posted a CW answer.

Comment: @Nishant: $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is not actually an example. It has $\mathbb{Z}[p^{-1}] / \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/\mathbb{Z}$ as proper subgroups. In fact, it is their direct sum.

Answer (score 1):

No. There are even abelian counterexamples, given in [Find an abelian infinite group such that every proper subgroup is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261145/). More examples are found in MathOverflow post [An infinite group such that every proper subgroup is finite?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120829/an-infinite-group-such-that-every-proper-subgroup-is-finite)